# Google Drive API without Ouath and receive files

Tags: google-drive-api, yql, google-drive-realtime-api

We are building a web application that should get all files from a specific folder in our Drive (read only). The problem is that I can't find a way to access our files without using OAuth. Basically I would want to request our files using AJAX and present the contents of them on a page (without the user having to do anything). Is this at all possible and have I missed something?

Whenever I try something without using OAuth I get a global internalError (being related to authorization according to the current documentation).

The experience I'm trying to achieve:

User enters http://domain.com/posts > Get all public files from folder Y > Sort them by date > Show the titles in HTML > User clicks title > User is presented with full contents of the file as HTML.

**Is this possible?**

Thanks in advance! :)

**UPDATE:**
To clarify: I would want to depend on our API key only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way, without using Google Drive API:

1. Make the folder public
2. Copy the *folder ID* from the URL
3. Append it to https://googledrive.com/host/ e.g. https://googledrive.com/host/0BzEbtMoF6IXbaVN2Qmx1em9qS0k/

You will get a directory index with all files listed and if the (sub)folder contains an *index.html* file, it will be rendered instead.

To get the JSON or XML file list, use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22https%3A//googledrive.com/host/0B_p1jUoXa8fqVG9sd0dXdFl5R2c/%22%20and%20xpath%3D%27//div%5b@class%3D%22folder-cell%22%5d/a%27).

Comment: that is awesome - but why is this hidden behind some off Google Linux OS page? It's not documented anywhere... or I am blind.

Comment: Would it be possible to make the index.html file contain a bunch of data and render it as json? That way a post, as described in the question, could simply visit this link using ajax and receive the data then render it any which way...

Comment: @mattdlockyer Sure it is possible, just use the JSON format while querying YQL.